# why two threads get scheduled in android poll_sched and epoll

Tags: android, multithreading, linux-kernel

I am trying to create thread using HandlerThread  in android code :Thread gets created but some how I see two instance of it.

But when run  "ps -t | grep pid" command to see the thread details , I see two threads getting generated  as below:

```
system    3421  3487   730544 88612 SyS_epoll_ b6d58ce4 S testThread
system    3422  3487   730544 88612 poll_sched b6d58eac S testThread
```

Can someone please let me know what is difference between sys_epoll and poll_sched and why two threads are created?

Does Select() api can cause  poll_sched ?

Comment: what exact `ps` command are you using? just `ps -t`?

Comment: ps -t | grep <pid>

Comment: ok so i have different `ps` command on my emulator then... btw if you think that `HT` makes any magic woodoo here you have what it does: http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java - as you can see its just a custom `Thread` which attaches `Lopper` in its `run` method - nothing more

Comment: I have refereed java files before posting this .  I do not hope to find any answer at java layer. I was kind of looking answer from linux/kernel stand point.

Comment: Can you check the kernel call stack ? `cat /proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/stack`

Comment: I get the output of it as 0000000|ffffffff.   Tried to killing the process with kill <pid>, did not get stack trace.  any idea how dump call stack would be helpfull.